# What are the responsibilities of, and differences between, a RecyclerView Adapter and RecyclerView LayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to understand the RecyclerView but I can't understand the difference between the Adapter and LayoutManager.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adapter is used to create (and bind data to) views that correspond to each item in your dataset.

The layout manager is responsible for the layout of these views.

The adapter doesn't know how the views will be positioned and sized. This means you can swap the layout manager without having to change your adapter code e.g. switching from a LinearLayoutManager to GridLayoutManager.

Check out this answer for a deeper (though still high-level) explanation (scroll past the initial code block to the section about RecyclerView philosophy):

[ListView to RecyclerView Migration for CustomView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028155/listview-to-recyclerview-migration-for-customview/32028411#32028411)

Answer (score 0):

So in Recycler View you need an Adapter to manage the data which will contain the Recycler view. Adapter will take the data it can come from internet or from internal database, than adapter fetches the dat when it gets the data without an error it comes back to adapter(e.g.adapter grabs data from dataset) then it shows the data in the View Holder  in your card like a one cell in the Recycler View, View Holder is a class that manages the view and than that view appears in the Recycler View. The above image which i tried to draw shows that process for Horizontal Recycler
[image: This image which i tried to draw shows that process for Horizontal Recycler]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i found these benifits when i working on them 
Basically an Adapter is used to gather all corresponding data what you provided 
to all views defined by you

after gathering all data it wants  a layout to display thease views  for this layoutmanager gives a flatform  to show them .